# Update multiple rows in a for each loop

Tags: php, pdo

I want to update multiple rows using pdo and update. For some reason it works for a single line update (inserted and overgiven from a html textarea) but not for multiple rows, so I think my bad is somewhere in the foreach loop which should update row by row.

**Overgiven from HTML textarea (changeAccountData):**

```
user|pass|region
user1|pass1|region1
```

**My Php part**

```
$accounts = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['changeAccountData']);

    $quantity = sizeof($accounts);
    // Batch size, calc iterations
    $batchSize = 500;


    for($idx=0;$idx*$batchSize < $quantity; $idx++){
        $accountsPartial = array_slice($accounts, $idx*$batchSize, $batchSize);

        // Prepare the Query
        $query = "UPDATE EasyService SET password=? WHERE username=? AND region=?";
        // Create the multiple value placeholder
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

        $i = 1;
        foreach($accountsPartial as $item){
            list($user, $pass, $region) = explode("|", $item);
            $stmt->bindValue($i++, trim($pass));
            $stmt->bindValue($i++, trim($user));
            $stmt->bindValue($i++, trim(strtoupper($region)));
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
```

I wonder whether I need to use bindValue or bindParam in such cases ? Why does this work for a single account but not for multiple accounts. I echoed all $user, $pass and $region already which was fine.

Comment: I believe it's because on the second loop, `$i` is 4. Put `$i=1` at the top of your `foreach` (on the inside)

Comment: Ofcourse you are right!! Thanks for looking into this. Sometimes I just need 2 more eyes :)

Comment: Also, I don't use `PDO`, so I'm not sure how it handles transactions, but if you're doing anything in a loop, it should be inside an SQL transaction.